Retrieving a reference to a service from instantiated dynamic module when using `createTestingModule`
Having the following definition of a global dynamic module:
// prisma.module.ts
import { DynamicModule, Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PrismaService } from 'nestjs-prisma'

@Global()
@Module({})
export class PrismaModule {
  static register(options: {
    databaseUrl: string
  }): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: PrismaModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: PrismaService,
          useFactory: () =>
            new PrismaService({
              prismaOptions: {
                datasources: {
                  db: {
                    url: options.databaseUrl,
                  },
                },
              },
            }),
        },
      ],
      exports: [PrismaService],
    }
  }
}

I'm using Test.createTestingModule to compile and test a module which is not a top-level AppModule (let's say MyModule). This module depends on the global, dynamic module PrismaModule, so I had to override it using the trick mentioned in this GitHub issue:
// app.module.ts

export const prismaModule = PrismaModule.register({
  databaseUrl: process.env.DB_URL,
})

@Module({
  imports: [
    // ...
    prismaModule,
    // ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}

// my-module.test.ts

import { prismaModule } from '../app.module'

// ...

const mockPrismaModule = PrismaModule.register({
  databaseUrl: "<some connection string>",
})

const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [prismaModule],
  controllers: [MyController],
  providers: [MyService],
})
  .overrideModule(prismaModule)
  .useModule(mockPrismaModule)
  .compile()

const prismaService = mockPrismaModule.<...>

Is there a way to get access to an instance of PrismaService of mockPrismaModule that the dynamic PrismaModule creates during register()? I've tried using mockPrismaModule.get(PrismaService) but it doesn't seem like it can be used in a way as you'd use the result of Test.createTestingModule().

You should be fine to use moduleRef.get(PrismaService, { strict: false })
